# WSO2 XML declaration in double quotes

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

For WSO2ei 6.3.0, by default respond mediator is including XML declaration in single quotes

`<? xml version=’1.0’ encoding=’UTF-8’?>`

were as we need the XML declaration as;

`<? xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Comment: Respond mediator doesn't do that there must be issues with your sequence, can you paste the entire sequence

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.